# Error : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am really sorry for putting this error again, but couldnt find any solution. I want to send mail from java application. I have written the following function for the same , it shows: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect .
I am certain something is wrong with the function but don't know exactly . Please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendMail {


public static void sendm(String from,String subject,String messagef) {    

      String to = "support@email.com";
      String from1 = from;   
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
      props.put("mail.stmp.user" , "support@email.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.debug", "false");
      props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

      try {
           MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from1));
           message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
           message.setSubject(subject);
           message.setText(messagef);
           Transport.send(message);
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to authenticate to gmail.com with an `@email.com` email-address, are you sure you are using the right mail server or username?

Comment: @mark username and password i have changed here. Its of google only .